# Staking Proxy and proxying it in turn

Tags: staking, proxy

I see that staking controller accounts cannot be created anymore, and instead Staking Proxy accounts are introduced.

Should a Staking Proxy, when staking on behalf a Stash account, post the staking call as a stash call packed within a proxying call, as other proxies do?

If the proxying chain is longer (eg. the Staking Proxy has nominated in its turn another Staking or Non-Transfer proxy, etc), should the last proxy account in the chain pack the corresponding number of proxying calls, from every proxy on behalf of its nominator, one within another?

Thank you in advance!